# iterate over first elements of a txt in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, parsing, loops

I have a txt file, and I want to count the number of elements in each line only for the first 3 rows.

I tried this:

```
for line in open('C:\Users\Gabriela\Documents\prueba_py.txt')[:3]:
    arr = line.strip().split('\t')
    print len(arr)
```

But doesn't work. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: `itertools.islice(open('C:\Users\Gabriela\Documents\prueba_py.txt'), 3)`

Comment: Always use a raw string with Windows based file path, otherwise things like `'\t'` will convert to a tab space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File Handles don't support slicing `[:3]`.  Perhaps you want `open().readlines()[:3]`?  Beware that loads the entire file in memory ... I'd use this instead:

```
for lineno, line in enumerate(open(...)):
  if lineno > 2:
    break
  # Remaining code here.
```